# Permissions for SharePoint Add-in App registration

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-addin, modern-experience, app

How can I see the permissions for a SharePoint Add-in App registration?

I once created it with `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx` and gave it permissions with `https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`.

Now I need to check what permission I gave it. I can get to the overview the link below, but cannot find the permissions.

```
https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/TA_AllAppPrincipals.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

To look up registration information for an add-in that you have registered, go to `http://<SharePointWebsite>/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx`.

To see a list of registered add-in principals (permissions), go to: `http://<SharePointWebsite>/_layouts/15/AppPrincipals.aspx`

**Official documentation**: [Retrieve add-in registration and add-in principal information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins#retrieve-add-in-registration-and-add-in-principal-information)

**Additional Reference**: [How can I view a list of applications added by AppRegNew.aspx?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163395/how-can-i-view-a-list-of-applications-added-by-appregnew-aspx)

Comment: Hi @Andreas, Does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with same problem in future. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list. If you have any doubt please ask here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to check the permissions of SharePoint add-in. The AppPrincipals can only view the app you registered but cannot view the permissions of the app. If you forget what permission you gave, I would suggest you create a new one.